# correct way to redirect changed site location via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-6

i used to host my site at www.mysite.com/here
now the url is simply www.mysite.com

so how do i properly redirect all old links from say www.mysite.com/here/about
to www.mysite.com/about

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteRule ^mysite.com/here(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

to your .htaccess so that the rewrite rules look something along the lines of

```
RewriteRule ^mysite.com/here(.*)$ http://mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

if you happen to have another /here path in you Drupal instance (e.g. a page), then it is more complicated and I would probably change that path.